# problem with sharepoint ssrs reports in safari

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sql-server, reporting-services, bi

hi we have sharepoint 2013 and sql server 2014 we use ssrs 2014  to show dashboards which get information from another sql server 2008 R2  we can see ashboards internally but over internet in iphone  phones  we cannot see dashboards we donot have this problem with android phones what should we do?

Answer (score 0):

As per [MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161353.aspx) Safari is supported so you may log a bug with MS.

There was one fix with modifying the js file to change overflow on the effective css (overflow from auto to visible on the container). But this hack is not supported as it overwrties the original js (which may be overwritten by SHarepoint update) but that was for  report not dashboard so not sure will that work for you. 
Have a look at: 
http://www.macaalay.com/2014/01/23/show-ssrs-reports-properly-in-chrome-and-safari/

Comment: we have report too but we donot have C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS11.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportManager\js address in our database server or sharepoint server what should I do

Comment: I would review the mobile page and check from where the files are loaded.